# Default font family name in latex to pass to commands?

Tags: fonts

I apologize if this should be obvious to me.

In short, I know that the default font family is called 'Computer Modern' but what value should I pass to the `monofont` field in the Pandoc metadata block (or to
other Latex commands if required)?

More elaborately, this is my situation:
I am using Pandoc and I want to change the size of the **monospace** font only (to accommodate the lines in my code block within the margin). For this, I know that I have to assign some suitable value to the `Scale` parameter under the `monofontoptions` field.

```
monofontoptions:
    - Scale=0.9
```

However [this](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/5491) issue says that you **must** mention the font name (through `monofont`) before the `monofontoptions` field. I know that this is true because I have tried it with a value that I *do know*
that is `inconsolata` which I had a hard time figuring out (after trying many combinations like `Inconsolata`, `Inconsolata.ttf`, etc). This works:

```
monofont: inconsolata # what should be the equivalent for the default monospace font?
monofontoptions: 
    - Scale=0.9
```

But as mentioned in the comment, I prefer the original monofont and as such want the "exact" name of the default font family. I know that Latex uses the 'Computer Modern' family and have tried variations like `computer modern`, `cm`, etc. But none seem to work. Any idea ?

In general, should I look at my font files to determine the name ?

Comment: I guess the font family is `cmtt`.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work: I get a stream of text in which one line says `!Package fontspec Error: The font "cmtt" cannot be found.`

Comment: I didn't you use fontspec. Do you have CM Unicode installed, per chance?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what that means but I have explictly installed only the Texlive distribution and the computer modern font files which are housed in my downloads directory. There are many of them and are named `cmnu..` like `cmnurm.ttf`, etc. My guess is that the `un` means Unicode so the answer to your question could be yes?

Comment: CM-Unicode exists in open type format, and is part of the TeX Live distribution. According to Nexus Font, the name of the tt font family is `CMU Typewriter Text`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user Bernard, who pointed out that it was an OpenType font, I used the following

```yaml
monofont: cmuntt
monofontoptions:
    - Extension=.otf
    - Scale=0.9
```

and it worked. As to how I figured out the name of the font, I ran a `kpsewhich` to know where the "primary" TeX directory was located on my system (when installing TeXLive). It was at `/usr/share/texlive`. So I ran the following command:

```
find /usr/share/texlive/ -name "*.ttf" -o -name "*.otf" 2>/dev/null -printf "%f\n" | grep "cmun"
```

which produced a list of all the fonts that of the Computer Modern family, one of which was `cmnuntt.otf` which I figured from the `tt` meant monospace.

I suppose this could be used to figure out other font names as well? which is why I am posting this because passing font names is something I have struggled with. Feel free to point out anything anything I could be missing or if this is an unnecessary hassle!